# Server is sending a request to Open Api Vision API with right credentials but getting invalid error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a server that I have recently created to interact with OpenAI's vision api. I went on their documentation and implemented the code for the server correctly. I am running into an issue every single time I submit a request to the api. I have Chat GPT plus that I pay for ever single month which should give me access to the api. I am not sure why it is telling me that the model is invalid or I do not have permission. Can someone help me.

Here is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const OpenAIApi = require("openai");
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY)
const openai = new OpenAIApi({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/v1/analyze-image', async (req, res) => {
    const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;

    if (!imageUrl) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'No image URL provided' });
    }

    try {
      const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model: "gpt-4-vision-preview",
        messages: [
          {
            role: "user",
            content: [
              { type: "text", text: "What’s in this image?" },
              {
                type: "image_url",
                image_url: {
                  "url": imageUrl,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      });

       res.json(response.data.choices[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is what I am getting back as a response:

```
{
    "error": "404 The model `gpt-4-vision-preview` does not exist or you do not have access to it. Learn more: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4."
}
```

Here is what the documentation says:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI();

async function main() {
  const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-4-vision-preview",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "user",
        content: [
          { type: "text", text: "What’s in this image?" },
          {
            type: "image_url",
            image_url: {
              "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Gfp-wisconsin-madison-the-nature-boardwalk.jpg/2560px-Gfp-wisconsin-madison-the-nature-boardwalk.jpg",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
  console.log(response.choices[0]);
}
main();
```

Not sure why it is saying I do not have access or the model is wrong. Is there anything else that can be causing this issue.

Comment: if you just made the payment, wait for a day and retry it

Comment: My last payment was Nov 14, 2023
$20.00
Paid
ChatGPT Plus Subscription so it is not the payment. That is why I am so confused... @Yilmaz

Comment: r u sure u updated `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY` this with the subscribed key

Answer (score 0):

In [this forum](https://community.openai.com/t/api-access-without-paying-for-a-chatgpt-plus-subscription/330848), you can find that the ChatGPT Plus Subscription and the API tokens are completely seperate products. To make use of the `gpt-4-vision-preview` and a lot of the other newer models, you need to put credits into your account. The billing via the API is dependent on the amount of tokens you use in your prompts and answers.

More on the token limits and payment plans for the API can be found in the [OpenAI Documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits?context=tier-one).